# Assigning names and types to the columns of an empty data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I found the following command to create an empty data frame whose columns have a name and a type:

```
dataFrameMio = data.frame("col1" = character(0), "col2" = numeric(0), "col3"= numeric(0))

class(dataFrameMio$col1)  # character OK
class(dataFrameMio$col2)  # numeric OK
class(dataFrameMio$col3)  # numeric OK
```

And I found this code where the type is automatically set to logical. Is it possible to specify the type also in this case?

```
colonne = c("col4", "col5", "col6")
dataFrameMio2 = data.frame((matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(colonne))))
colnames(dataFrameMio2) = colonne
print(dataFrameMio2)

class(dataFrameMio2$col4)  # logical
class(dataFrameMio2$col5)  # logical
class(dataFrameMio2$col6)  # logical
```

Comment: `matrix` can have only a single type

Comment: Hello @akrun only the logical one?

Comment: You specified `nrow = 0`, and thus it by default changes to logical.  check `matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = length(colonne)) %>% str
 logi[0 , 1:3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just that `matrix` cannot have more than one type.  It may be either better to create a `list` and wrap to `data.frame` as `list` can have multiple types.  Or if we want to change the type

```
dataFrameMio2[] <- Map(`class<-`, dataFrameMio2, 
   c("character", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

-checking

```
> str(dataFrameMio2)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col4: chr 
 $ col5: num 
 $ col6: num 
> class(dataFrameMio2$col4)
[1] "character"
> class(dataFrameMio2$col5)
[1] "numeric"
> class(dataFrameMio2$col6)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: if I wrote class(dataFrameMio$col4) the output is NULL instead of character. Why?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi `class` for `dataFrameMio2` each column gives the expected. (please check my post)

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I think this was the issue.  Earlier, I forgot the `[]`, thus it returned a `list` and I didn't check it.  Now corrected please check